# multiple developers working with multiple branches efficiently

Tags: git, git-branch

I'm a developer which uses git just for very basic purposes but right now the developers team has increased a bit and I find out my git skills may not be the best ones to manage a git repository used for multiple developers. So I wonder if the following working behavior is the best one we can follow for the above scenario:

We're 5 developers working on a single git repository.
Each developer works on his own branch, so he's only allowed to commit and push on his branch.
We have a master branch where to store stable code used to provide a pre production environment.
We have a develop branch where we merge and so store code pushed by each developer on his own branch.

The working flow is the following:

```
#First time
git clone git@domain:my_repository.git
git checkout develop
git checkout -b my_branch

#Everyday before coding, developers fetch and merge develop branch
git fetch --all
git rebase origin/develop

git commit -m 'Some work done' src/
#before push, fetch and merge again develop branch changes
git fetch --all
git rebase origin/develop
git push origin my_branch
#Only when previous push is blocked, the following command should be run
git rebase origin/my_branch
git push origin my_branch

Now, someone has to update develop branch so developers can always work with the last version of the code developer by his team mates
git fetch --all

git checkout some_developer_branch
git pull origin some_developer_branch
git rebase origin/develop
git push origin some_developer_branch

git checkout develop
git pull origin develop
git merge some_developer_branch
git push origin develop

#Now i repeat the process again in order to merge another developer branch.
```

Seeing that's a tidy process which forces me to keep develop branch up to date to let developers fetch and merge other team mates code, I wonder if that's the best behavior to avoid code conflicts and to have each developer working with the last version of the code.

Comment: IMO that's risky: if one developer breaks his branch then the next day everyone will have the broken change. Why not let people complete whole tasks and then merge when that's done? Assuming tasks are relatively short timescales that ought not let the branches diverge too much.

Comment: @Donal How would GitHub help? It adds a prettier UI but I don't think it'd help the process.

Comment: Risky, thanks a lot for your help. Right now the issue it's not about some developer breaking the code but to be able to code on a relative updated branch so final merges into developer or master branch does not generate conflicts. Also i would like to note developers only push non breaking code, they also have a tmp branch for incomplete code. I designed that work flow because developers usually ended up with outdated branches and then merging their code into develop or master was a nightmare. All i'm asking is for a workflow which let us code and avoid conflicts. thanks again for your time!

Comment: Have a look at http://www.sourcetreeapp.com. We have used it before and it can help resolve conflicts.

Answer (score 2):

We use a remote server that has the repository.  We have the developers clone it and work on their own develop branch.  Once their changes are working they will then do a pull, commit and push.   This keeps the remote repository up to date so everyone can get the latest code.

Normally I do a pull first thing in the morning to get all the latest code and then if I have anything to commit during the day I still do a pull to be up to date before a push.   If I do forget the pull or there is a merge conflict, depending on what it is I will either go ahead and do my commit so the merge can occur or I will do a stash so I can deal with the merge after the pull.

This way works for us and seems a lot simpler than your example above with fewer commands.  Perhaps all you really need is another machine on your network to host the repository instead of you.  At least that is what it seems like to me is that you are hosting the repository instead of having it on a different machine.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Bob, thanks a lot for your help. If i understand correctly, the flow you proposed is equal to mine. Developers work on their branch, which is always up to date, before start coding and before pushing. Before going home i rebase each developer branch so they can fetch and merge changed next day morning. Obviously repository is not hosted on my development machine but in a cloud server. Thanks for sharing your expertise!

Comment: I don't understand why you need to rebase each developer yourself. In our case each developer is responsible for their own local copy and everything on the server is kept up to date without anyone having to do anything to it.

Comment: Someone has to merge/rebase developer's branches into master, isn't it?

Comment: Oh, I see now.   You are merging the changes from develop to master.  In our case master is being left alone until we ship and then master will be updated.  While we are working on the release all code is pushed to develop and everyone pulls from develop.    The master branch is left alone.    I assume you are doing something with your master branch and that is why you are keeping it up to date one a daily basis.

Comment: The idea is our developers only work with their branch, which must always be updated before start coding and before pushing. Then the leader must merge, before leaving, all branches into develop. But that work flow is still generating conflicts, probably some junior developer is not following the manual, so i wonder if there's a better approach? Thx!!